# PHP mail() issue if it containg URL

Tags: php, php-ini

I am trying to send simple html email using PHP mail().

The following code work **fine**

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
If(mail('xyz@gmail.com', 'test mail', 'test<hr>this is a test mail', $headers)){
  Echo 'OK';
} else{
  Echo 'Not ok';
}
```

**Problem**: as soon as I put <strike>some</strike> specific url in the body the code still say its ok but email never received

```
If(mail('xyz@gmail.com', 'test mail', 'test<hr>this is a test mail from www.xyz.com', $headers)){
  Echo 'OK';
} else{
  Echo 'Not ok';
}
```

Can someone guide me whats the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: send your message to this site to see if the server acting with it as a spam http://www.mail-tester.com

Comment: First change all your `‘ ’` to normal `'` That alone will produce undesirable results, being `Parse error:...` and `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@'`

Comment: Have you set the mail config properly?

Comment: @Shah *"The following code work fine"*, it would have thrown you a parse error. I tested your above code and that's what my results were. See my answer below, fully tested. Notes are inside also. DO NOT USE irregular apostrophes, also known as "backticks", which is what you presently have.

Comment: My apologies, i typed few lines in word. I updated the code.
code works fine every where its just got issue with godaddy. I trying with their support from last 3 days but in vain. So i end up here that some one might guide me about it.

Comment: Links in an email should match the domain you're sending from.

Comment: @Jack its strange with me. It send every URL except from the domain itself. When ever i put a url with the domain itself e-g password recovery url for the domain the email sent from the code but never received on the destination.  any ideas is this blocked by SMTP sever or something else??

Answer (score 1):

`mail()` has a 4th and 5th parameter (optional). The 5th argument is what should be passed as options directly to sendmail . use the following:

```
$body = 'test<hr>this is a test mail from'.htmlentities('www.xyz.com');

if(mail('xyz@gmail.com','test mail', $body,$headers,'-f from@xyz.com'))
{
....
}
```

hope it work now :)

**and while searching for mail do check your spam folder.**

Comment: Thanks its working but i guess the problem is, its blocking email that contains specific domains. any ideas what could be the reason and how to fix that?